Support for preloading in Blazor WebAssembly Lazy Loading
I have implemented lazy loading for Blazor WebAssembly as per the code below.
When all required web assemblies have been loaded, I would like to load the rest of the web assemblies that have not yet been loaded.
Is there some built-in support for this?
If no, is there any event I can use to implement this on my own?
@inject ILogger<App> Logger
@inject LazyAssemblyLoader AssemblyLoader


<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="LazyLoadedAssemblies" OnNavigateAsync="HandleNavigateAsync">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    public List<Assembly> LazyLoadedAssemblies { get; set; } = [];

    private async Task HandleNavigateAsync(NavigationContext args)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (args.Path)
            {
                case "Customer":
                    {
                        List<string> assemblyNamesForThisPath = ["BlazorWebAssemblyStandalone.Customer.wasm"];

                        var assemblies = await AssemblyLoader.LoadAssembliesAsync(assemblyNamesForThisPath);

                        LazyLoadedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblies);

                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError("Error: {Message}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

